# Responsive image size and position in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I'm designing a simple website in HTML and CSS but got stuck. I'd like my website to have an image at the top. Any content that comes after that image should appear underneath the image, not on top of it (like it does with a background image). The image should  be 0.6 (or some other fraction) the height of the viewport and centered. Any overflowing part should be cropped. However, in case the image is too narrow, it should be resized to fill the whole width of the viewport. It should never change its apect ratio. I'd also like to keep my site **script-free** and would like to have **no absolute values** (like `px`) in my source files.

Here are some doodles I made to explain my idea:

Image height is set to 0.6vh. It is centered. The overflowing areas are cropped. Text starts at the bottom.
[image: case 1]

Image height would be set to 0.6vh but it wouldn't cover the whole viewport's width. Instead, set the image width to match the viewport width (equal to the width of the page), ignoring the 0.6vh rule. Text still starts at the bottom.
[image: case 2]

I've been searching the internet for two days already but I couldn't really find quite what I need.

Additionaly, I am trying to solve this problem: currently, I am using `vh` to set the height of the image, but it gets weird when viewing on a mobile browser, because the value of `vh` changes when the address bar collapses.

[EDIT]

Rule:

1. The **minimum** width of the image should be the width of the viewport.
2. Then, if it's possible, it's height should match 0.6`vh`.

[EDIT 2]

I noticed that the answers work great by centering an image and keeping it's aspect ratio. But the image shouldn't be cropped vertically.

Another doodle:

I hope this doodle makes it easier to see what I am trying to achieve. Red line indicates the "0.6vh rule" while blue line represents the "mininimal width equals viewport width" rule. Green rectangle shows where the image should be.
[image: case 3]

[EDIT 4]

I added an image and some comments to the previous image:
[image: case 4]

Comment: When do you want to jump back and forth between the layouts? Is this like a mobile and desktop thing? How do you know when to trigger the different look?

Comment: These are just examples. The image should be adjusted for any viewport size.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are these 2 different layouts, or does one become the other when certain conditions are met? What is the width of the first example supposed to be? If an image is too narrow, how/why would it become the width of the entire viewport and not be stretched? And where is your code of what you've actually tried?

Comment: See the edit. I hope I made it clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Check out my updated answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using an image tag, try setting its properties in CSS.  It's easier to maintain aspect ratio and centering this way.  You may also want to specify a minimum and maximum height property to ensure things look nice.

```css
    body{
      margin: 0; /* Stripping out margin and padding so .bg can be full width*/
      padding: 0;
    }
    .bg {
      box-sizing: border-box; 
      display: block; 
      width: 100%;  
      height: 60vh; /* 60vh = 60% of the viewport height*/
      padding: 0; /* No padding */
      margin: 0; /* No margins */
      background-image: url('http://www.naturheilpraxis-kaelin.ch/bilder/fruehling-01.jpg'); 
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center center;  
      background-size: cover; /* Cover all available space. */ 
      /* If you want the whole image visible try 'contain'*/
    }
    .main{
      padding: 0 1em; /* L/R padding to look nice */
    }
```

```html
  <body>
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <article class="main">
  <h1>Your rad site</h1>
  <p>Notice how the image is centered and it keeps its aspect ratio.</p>
  </article>
  </body>
```

---

#### [EDIT]

Okay! So here's the best I can do.
This doesn't crop anything vertically and there's no JS or hard values
BUT you do have to use an aspect ratio media query that you need to figure out based on your image.

This is the formula for the aspect ratio media query
Where `H = image height`, `W = image width` and `D = percent of the viewport used` (expressed as a decimal).

> H / (W / (D))

For example, the image I used is `1000px` x `300px`. We're using `60%` of the viewport so `D = .6`.
So `1000 / (300 / (.6))` >> `1000 / 500` >> `2/1` ratio.

```css
body,html,.container{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 60vh;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  /* Position the image in the middle of its container. */
  /* Hack*/
  top: -9999px;
  right: -9999px;
  bottom: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-aspect-ratio:
2/1) { 
/*  Aspect ratio determined like so -- H / (W * (10/6)) */ 
  .container img{
    position: relative; /*Undoing the hack basically*/
    right: auto;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    width: 100%; /*rather than the width get cropped, it's full. height is auto*/
}
  .container {height: auto; /* the image height determines the height */}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x300" alt="" />
</div>
```

Make it full page and resize the browser to see how the image adapts.
I really hope that helps!

Comment: Maybe using an actual image in your mockups will make the desired effect clearer.  As it is now I'm sorry to say I can't understand what it is you want.

Comment: Aah, thank you. I finally think I understand what you want.  On really wide screens, if needed you want the image height to exceed the original 60vh to keep the full height on the image in view. Correct?

Comment: *to keep the full width of the image in the view - yes

Answer (score 1):

How about an approach like this:

```css
body,html {margin: 0;padding: 0}
* {box-sizing: border-box}

/*For the demo I've made the height below 30vh, you can change that to 6vh*/
/*Use background-size contain, if your image's height is larger that width*/
.Image-Banner {width: 100%;height: 30vh;background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj9LO.png') no-repeat 50%;background-size: cover}

.Main-Content {padding: 1em}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class='Image-Banner'></header>
  <main class='Main-Content'>
    <div>Foo Bar</div>
    <hr>
    <aside>Lorem Ipsum...</aside>
  </main>
</body>
```

***Note:*** Click **`Run Code Snippet`** to see the result.

This should do exactly what you are asking for, I believe.

Comment: I tested it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yqf3333h/), but the aspect ratio of the image is changing. I need it to be fixed.

Comment: Changed, with comment

Comment: What you are asking for is impossible w/o javascript, unless you know the width of the image at 6vh at all times

Comment: Well, I guess I will have to use absolute values in my source code. I'd like my website to be working without scripts.

Comment: Precisely why I didn't adjust my answer to include the JS to match that. There are two approaches you can take, You can either have the website scale up the _height of he image_ as the web-page grows in width (_with the overflow cut off_), or have the width overflow cut off (as the height grows/shrinks). With the added enhancement to have the background match the edges of the image (_so you can't tell where the image ended_)

Answer (score 0):

Created an example based on your information:

```
[Example][1]


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lke94qn/1/
```

Let say that we have two divs:

```
<div class="top">Top</div>
<div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
```

Try this style:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
.top{
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  background-image: url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/HD-Wallpapers1.jpeg");
  background-position: center;
}
.bottom{
  background-color: grey;
  height: 40%;
}
```

Comment: So where is the problem?

Comment: See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh9t3dbq/). It's ok untill the viewport is wider than the image. In that case the image should be resized so its width matches the viewport width, not vertically repeated.

Comment: Sorry. I meant horizontally repeated.

Comment: It's recommended to use background image at least 1600px width. Are you looking for this: [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/besartm/6zb15v2a/)